# PDF Files greater than 10 mb are not displaying using PDFobject.js

Tags: pdf, pdfobject

Ive been using PDFObject.js in my page to display pdf files. I notice when the pdf file is greater than 10 mb, it doesnt display in my viewer. Is there any way I can fix it? Any alternative tools I can use aside from PDFObject to display pdf files without file size limitation?

Answer (score 0):

All PDFObject does is write the HTML markup for you (puts an `<object>` on the page for you). It does not have any bearing on the size of PDFs, and does not impose any size limitations.

As a comparison, try embedding with static publishing (pure markup, no JS) and see if it makes a difference.

It's more likely a network issue, an issue with the PDF reader, or a corrupt PDF. Have you had the same results in every browser?